# Can't use SSH anymore after installing denyhosts

Tags: ssh, debian, denyhosts

so I'm in a very tricky situation. I've installed denyhosts on my debian machine and suddenly I can't use SSH anymore.

Hopefully I could still login through webmin, but with root, so I had to login with another user and then "su".

I flushed the IPtables, changed the port of SSH back to 22 (I had it previously changed) and tried to remove denyhosts : aptitude remove denyhosts.

It doesn't seem to work:

E: Waited for /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -ne 10 but it wasn't the re                                                                               E: Failure running script /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -ne 10

at this point I really don't know what to do, I still can't connect through SSH and I only have this text terminal in webmin that allows me to do it but very slowly. Any idea ?

PS:

When I do an aptitude upgrade now I get an error:

```
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main file amd64 5.04-5+squeeze 5 [50.3 kB]                                                                      
Get:2 http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main libmagic1 amd64 5.04-5+sq ueeze5 [236 kB]                                                                  
Fetched 286 kB in 0s (622 kB/s)                                                  
dpkg-deb: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:                                    
wait for subprocess tar failed: No child processes                              
close failed in file object destructor:                                          
IOError: [Errno 10] No child processes                                          
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                 
File "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges", line 237, in <module>                             main()                                                                         
File "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges", line 102, in main                                 
pkg = DebianFiles.Package(deb)                                                 
File "/usr/share/apt-listchanges/DebianFiles.py", line 133, in __init__            
self.binary  = pkgdata.Package                                               
AttributeError: ControlStanza instance has no attribute 'Package'                
E: Waited for /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -ne 10 but it wasn't the re                                                                               
E: Failure running script /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -ne 10       A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
```

I get the same kind of error when I do a install or reinstall denyhosts...

Comment: Have you checked that you have enough space left on the server's hard disk?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`denyhosts` works by adding entries to `/etc/hosts.deny` file for IP addresses it finds violating the rules you have set up for it.

It seems that you tried to log in as `root` via SSH and mistyped the password once. By default, `denyhosts` adds an IP address to `/etc/hosts.deny` file after one failed login attempt for root account.

Even if you uninstall `denyhosts`, the entries will still stay in that file. So, you should edit `/etc/hosts.deny` file and remove entries relating to your IP address.

It also seems that you allow root logins via ssh. I don't think this is a good practice, you should log in as a normal user and use su to get root permissions. So, you should edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, and change `PermitRootLogin` to no.

Comment: yes, I did a > /etc/hosts.deny, now SSH works :)

Comment: I just reinstalled denyhosts, and I receive a mail that he banned my IP again. I haven't done anything wrong, isn't that odd?

Comment: Can also add your IP addresses to `/etc/hosts.allow` which takes precedence over entries in `/etc/hosts.deny`.

Comment: Your `auth.log` most likely still contained the failed `root` login attempt from earlier, and the reinstall of `denyhosts` made it read the `auth.log` again, causing the ban of the IP address. I strongly recommend you to stop using `root` remote login.

Comment: denyhosts stores bad ip addresses in several files in $WORK_DIR (specified in /etc/denyhosts.conf). You must remove the IP address from all of those files while denyhosts is stopped or it will re-add the ip to hosts.deny.

Answer (score 1):

To remove an IP address from denyhosts to allow that machine to connect again, the IP address must be removed from /etc/hosts.deny as well as all the files in the denyhosts WORK_DIR location while denyhosts is stopped. See [the denyhosts FAQ](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/faq.html#3_19) for the full procedure. Failure to remove the IP address from any of those files will cause denyhosts to re-add the address to hosts.deny and block connections.